# Node.js error: 'Can't set headers after they are sent' on post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, nunjucks

Ok, this topic as been answered a lot of times on stackoverflow, but I didn't find anything usefull for me.

I've setup a nodejs server and the 'get' queries works fine but when I'm trying to post, I get this error and it's written 'Cannot post /fr/login' (the url is domain.com/fr/login)

Just so you know, I'm using Express, i18n and Nunjucks as a templating engine.

I really don't know what's going on. I'm trying to make a login system but this is stopping me to do so. Sa bassically what's going on, is that the user input it's infos and then I call `User.findOne` with the mail and the password and then it should trigger the callback with the error that happen (successful login is considered an error). Currently, it does callback and 'transfer' to the callback the user information. (You might see a `console.log` in the callback, it is working). But when it triggers the res.render I get the two errors.

Here are my files:

1. server.js

   ```
   app.post('/:lang/login', getChangelog, getAlert, function(req, res) { 

     i18n.setLocale(req, req.params.lang);
       let version;
       if(req.cookies.version) {
          version = req.cookies.version;
       }
       if(!version) version = 0;

       var email = req.body.mailconnect;
       var password = req.body.mdpconnect;

       User.findOne({ email: email, password: password }, function(err, user){
         if(user['error'] != "LOGIN OK") {
           console.log(user);
           errorInfo['showError'] = true;
           errorInfo['error-msg'] = req.__("Error-WrongMail");
           res.render('login/login.njk', { title: req.__('Login-PageTitle'), 
   style: 'login.css', alertInfo: alertInfo, errorInfo: errorInfo, version: version, currVersion: currVersion, firstVersion: firstVersion, changelog: changelog });
         } else {
           var hash = user["mdp"];
           hash = hash.replace(/^\$2y(.+)$/i, '$2a$1');
           bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, res2) {
             if(res2){
               errorInfo['showError'] = false;
               errorInfo['error-msg'] = "LOGIN OK";

               res.redirect(i18n.getLocale + '/agent/' + user["id"] + '/selectservice');
             } else{
               errorInfo['showError'] = true;
               errorInfo['error-msg'] = req.__("Error-MailAndPassNoMatch");
               res.render('login/login.njk', { title: req.__('Login-PageTitle'), style: 'login.css', alertInfo: alertInfo, errorInfo: errorInfo, version: version, currVersion: currVersion, firstVersion: firstVersion, changelog: changelog });
             }
           });
         }
       });
     });
   ```
2. user.js

   ```
   var db = require('../other/mysql.js');
   exports.findOne = (data, callback) => {
   if(data.email != "" && data.password != "") {
     db.connection.query('SELECT * FROM membres WHERE mail = ?', data.email)
      .on('result', function (row) {

        let user = new Object();
        user = row;
        user['error'] = 'WrongMail'; //Temporary, just for testing

        callback(null, user);

      })
      .on('error', function (err) {
        let user = new Object();
        user['error'] = 'SQL';
        callback(err, user});
     });
    }
   }
   ```
3. mysql.js

   ```
   var mysql = require('mysql');

   var pool = mysql.createPool({
     connectionLimit : 10,
     host: "ip",
     user: "user",
     password: "password",
     database: "databse"
   });

   exports.connection = {
       query: function () {
           var queryArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
               events = [],
               eventNameIndex = {};

   pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
       if (err) {
           if (eventNameIndex.error) {
               eventNameIndex.error();
           }
       }
       if (conn) { 
           var q = conn.query.apply(conn, queryArgs);
           q.on('end', function () {
               conn.release();
           });

           events.forEach(function (args) {
               q.on.apply(q, args);
           });
       }
   });

   return {
       on: function (eventName, callback) {
           events.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
           eventNameIndex[eventName] = callback;
           return this;
       }
   };
   }
   };
   ```
4. This is my nodejs log

   ```
   RowDataPacket {
      id: 1,
      mail: 'mymail',


       matricule: '972',
       mdp: 'an hashed password',
       num_vehicle: 8001,
       profession: 'agent',
       dispatch: 'Y',
       supervisor: 'Y',
       admin: 'Y',
       status: 1,
       tkn: '3faixj17guocz89zfdx5a9',
       serv: '',
       error: 'WrongMail' }


       Caught exception:  Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
          at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
          at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
          at ServerResponse.header (F:\GitHub\terminal.ga\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:730:10)
          at ServerResponse.send (F:\GitHub\terminal.ga\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
   at done (F:\GitHub\terminal.ga\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:967:10)
   at F:\GitHub\terminal.ga\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:37:5
   at RawTask.call (F:\GitHub\terminal.ga\node_modules\asap\asap.js:40:19)
   at flush (F:\GitHub\terminal.ga\node_modules\asap\raw.js:50:29)
   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
   ```

Comment: Are you sure that `getChangelog` or `getAlert` middlewares doesn't send some data? Also, you don't have a `callback` when one of `data.email` or `data.password` is empty in `user.js`.

Comment: That I know, I was trying to make it work before handling empty variables. And yes I'm sure the middlewares aren't the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was my problem. The query returned results more than on time so it was calling the callback more than one time.

To fix this, I created a new exports that just get a connection from the pool and perform a query just like in the docs. A very simpel way to be sure it does not send data more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i am facing so many times.For me this error occur two times:

1. When I send response more than one in one callback.
2. When I am  not able to set the correct query result conditions in callback for executing other statement after getting result.

can you  post also app.js with that route call only @Willbill360

Comment: Try to add explicit return statement after the res.send statements. I was having the same issue and this helped me.

Comment: My server.js is the app.js and the only code I posted for server.js is the post route.